# Mouse scrolling doesn't work in Windows 10 Modern Apps

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling, modern-ui, windows-10-v1709

My mouse scroll wheel doesn't work in Windows 10 "modern apps" (Metro apps). This includes the start menu and the Settings. It works perfectly fine in 'classic apps' though.

I've already read many suggestions, saying that I should enable "scroll inactive windows" in the settings - however this option is turned on, on my device.

I'm running the latest windows 10 version (1709 build 16299.19). And I've tested it with 3 difference mice (however they were all logitech mice - I don't have any other brands, so I couldn't test em out)

Comment: Are you running any mouse software? Try uninstalling any Logitech software on you computer that is related to the Mouse.

Comment: I've uninstalled all Logitech software I had (setpoint, etc.). But it still doesn't work